# How to render a view triggered by an event in other view?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to create instant search using backbone.js. I'm planning to hold search box in one view. The entire content in other view. If the user types anything in the search view the collection in the other view gets updated automatically. I don't want code but some comments if the approach is right or wrong or what will the best approach be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On initialize, you can have both the search box and search results view referencing the same collection. On keyup/change of the search field you call a method (or trigger an event) on the collection to update the search term and call fetch. Then you have the search results view set up to automatically re-render on the change event of the collection.